# Sum and if cycle Matlab

Tags: matlab, sum

I have two questions and need your help.
This is my code;

```
for k=13:32
  for j=53:64
    if semana1(1,13)*Condicao_compra_energia >= semana1(1,53) & sum(semana1(1,k))< 800
      Custo_compra_semana1=semana1(1,k)*semana1(2,k);
      Total_Cost=sum(custo_compra_semana1);
      Potencia_comprada=sum(semana1,k);
      Sold =Potencia_comprada*semana1(1,53); 
      Profit = Sold-Total_Cost; 
    else ...

    end
  end
```

I need to set a condition to see if the sum between `semana1(1,13)` and `semana1(1,32)` are less than 800.

But when I make the sum like `sum(semana1(1,k))` I do not get the sum of that numbers, how can I resolve this?

My second issue is that after using the if condition when I put

```
Custo_compra_semana1 = semana1(1,k) * semana1(2,k); 
Total_Cost = sum(Custo_compra_semana1); 
Potencia_comprada=sum(semana1, k); 
Sold =Potencia_comprada*semana1(1,53); 
Profit = Sold-Total_Cost;
```

I need to get a matrix for `custo_compra_semana1`, ​​and `Total_Cost` should be the total value of the sum of this matrix, but what I'm getting in `custo_compra_semana1` is not a matrix and `Total_Cost` only gives the last value of `custo_compra_semana1`.

Comment: Just a question, you have not created a variable `sum`, have you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

semana(1,k) is a scalar value, you should specify a range

```
sum(semana1(1,13:32))< 800
```

To get a matrix with Custo_compra_semana1, you need to multiply two vectors, not two scalars

```
      Custo_compra_semana1=semana1(1,13:32)'*semana1(2,13:32);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help on the second question I used custo_compra=semana1(1,13:32).*semana1(2,13:32) instead.

Answer (score 1):

**First question:**

In order to set the correct condition, you should do this:

```
sum(semana1(1,13:32))< 800
```

Using `k` you are using ONLY 1 number from the array `semana1`.

**Second question:**

I cannot respond. You are not getting a matrix for the same reason (you are using onl 1 value). Additionally I don't know if `semana1` is a matrix and what part of the matrix are you interested in.